# What determines the level of new heros?

Tags: dungeon-of-the-endless

In particular, when I use Wes' ability to trigger a hero behind the next door, I've seen a level 2 hero appear when my other heros are level 8, which is... useless. What determines the level of the hero? Is it different than heros that appear naturally?